# Can you make the onTap in a ListTile open another ListTile underneath it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a list of different ListTiles and when tapped on, want them to open two more ListTiles directly underneath with specific information. When pressed on again, I want them to be removed. Can someone please help?
This is what I have so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page5 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page5State createState() => _Page5State();
}

class _Page5State extends State<Page5> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(''
            'Names',
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body:
      ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
            Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Text(
                    'Susan',
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                       )
                     ),
            Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Text(
                    'Steve',
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                        )
                   ),

                 ]
            )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ExpansionTile`.
It's like a normal `ListTile` but it takes a `children` parameter where you put the widgets you want to appear when it is clicked.

```
ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(
    'Your 1st ListTile',
  ),
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: Text('1'),
    )
    ListTile(
      title: Text('2'),
    )
    ListTile(
      title: Text('3'),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SliverList. I think that it is the best solution for your case. There is a video explaining how to use it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html